Citing volatile sources
What can be recommended for citing content on the internet that may be subject to modification or deletion without providing any means of restoring specific versions or of seeing deleted content?
In my case I want to cite a comment that I left on a social network (Linkedin) because in that comment I sketched the solution to problem that is the subject of a publication.

Is it on Mathoverflow? The right thing to do, then is to post your solution as an answer, not a comment and the cite it using the usual protocol for MO citation.

@MoisheKohan Looks like a great solution; you should post it as an answer rather than as a comment.

@FedericoPoloni: I would if I knew that it was Mathoverflow (or Mathstackexchange or somewhere else on this network). But I do not know, maybe it is on reddit or something similar. Thus, it is a question-comment, not an answer-comment.

@MoisheKohan it is on LinkedIn and was the answer to a mathematical puzzle. LinkedIn gives no guarantee for the persistence of links and is actually not suitable for resolving priority disputes, etc.

Oh, I see (personally, I stay away from LinkedIn for a variety of reasons). Then maybe you should clarify this in your post.

@MoisheKohan I have edited my question accordingly; I didn't do so in the first place because I feared being accused for advertising that platform...

@MoisheKohan But this is useful information that answers the question even if it is not the site OP is referring to; it should be posted as an answer anyway. In my experience, it is best to think to SE as a curated list of FAQ, not as a forum where we solve each user's individual problem.

To me the key here is that you want to refer to your own comment. I think it quite usual to informally discuss ideas/solution sketches e.g. with colleagues, at conferences in the coffee break or nowadays on social media before they are formalized into a full manuscript. In my field all this is normal, and (but) never mentioned in the paper. I'd thus neither mention the LinkedIn discussion, unless the puzzle there is cited in the motivation part.

(Nor do we cite conference talks given on the topic before writing up the paper, which are also quite common)

After your clarification, here is my suggestion:
Post a duplicate solution on arXiv (if you think it is suitable) or/and on one of the StackExchange sites (self-answering a question). In the post, note where did the problem originate. If the original source disappears, you at least have a duplicate to refer to. Afterwards (assuming that you need to cite it in a real publication), refer to it using the usual citation protocol citing both the original LinkedIn post and the post on a StackExchange site.

Use the wayback machine/internet archive (http://web.archive.org/) to archive it and cite that.  It will give you a stable source (for as long as it exists).  Each archive is timestamped with the time and date the archive was made, and you can take multiple snapshots if the page changes substantially.
Example in the comment below:

This appears to be a comment - the old version can still be seen here: http://web.archive.org/web/20241226141329/https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/215758/citing-volatile-sources/215759#comment582722_215759

Does the wayback machine work for LinkedIn pages? Their pages are not accessible unless one joins, which I haven't, so I can't check whether one can save their pages with the wayback machine.

@DaveLRenfro I don't know (the linkedin in info was not provided when I gave my answer) - having said which I'm not sure there is much point in citing what is essentially a private discussion forum, in which case republishing it on a public site is probably better (but that wasn't the question).

In addition to the advice of Dikran Marsupial you should always provide a date on which you accessed any potentially volatile material. In case the internet archive hasn't captured it you have a record established, and even for resources that are periodically archived, one may be able to get to the version you cite.
Even when you cite a book, you give the edition number for the same reason.
And beware of the fact that no internet resource can be guaranteed to exist in, say, 50 years, since both the technology and the economic interest has to last for that to happen. For some things, even five years is optimistic.

The capture on Internet Archive is dated, so if you archive soon after making the comment it should be satisfactory for establishing priority etc.

For the last paragraph, I fully agree - the internet archive is a great resource (as is Wikipedia) that could do with long term support to carry on doing what it is doing!

Besides the other advice you've been given, I would recommend making a copy for your personal records by printing the website to PDF, or similar. Should things disappear from the source website and archive.org you'd still have a copy to consult and send to others. Such a PDF can also be useful as a reference to check if any changes have been made to the website version (though that seems unlikely in case of a comment authored by yourself). This technique is also useful to archive non-public information such as emails that one might want to cite as private communication.

As an alternative to specific solutions others suggested - I have seen multiple times citations like “x, y and a, b - private communication”. Since your mentioned LinkedIn pages are similar in a sense that they are restricted to followers, a similar citation style could perhaps work.
Since this is your comment anyway, and the article is recreating that result in a formal way, I suspect you’re including the entire content of the relevant part anyway (as opposed to directing the reader to the comment for the proof of a result). In this case, perhaps something like this would suffice: “This result was first presented by the author on June 12 2021 in a private communication over LinkedIn.”

good idea to cite it as private communication; I think I'll modify it a little bit to state the accessibility in the vein of "publicly accessible private communication on Linkedin" to reflect the different privacy levels that are offered for communication on social network platforms.

@ManfredWeis Sure, that could work also. Ultimately, if there’s anything problematic with your citation, it’ll be caught during article review anyway. I wouldn’t sweat it too much, especially since the content of the citation is yours and will be completely included in the paper, making the citation merely ticking an academic code.
